# Firewall config

Tags: firewall

I am trying to see if it's possible and what commands need to be done. I am trying to block all outbound traffic to a specific ip on my local network. The back story is I am using plex and I don't want the plex app on my kodi box connecting to the local server, I am only going to use the plex server for remote viewing. Any help would appriciate do.

Brian

Answer (score 0):

I'd use UFW.

```
sudo apt-get install ufw
```

and run it like this:

```
sudo ufw deny from any to 123.123.123.123
```

Change the IP to what you want to block. Ensure it worked:

```
sudo ufw status
```

You can always undo this by putting `delete` right after `ufw`, like this:

```
sudo ufw delete dny from any to 123.123.123.123
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `sudo apt install gufw` to view the firewall configuration in GUI. [GUFW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaYqc.png)